# JavaScript factory that relies on jQuery and moment

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017

I am using VisualStudio 2017 .Net MVC though mostly this is a javascript app.  I am trying to create a library for the app.  I have not used factories before and am basing this on a few existing libs.  The samples I am using all start with a construct similar to:

```
    (function(factory) {
        if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
            define([ 'jquery', 'moment' ], factory);
        }
        else if (typeof exports === 'object') { // Node/CommonJS
            module.exports = factory(require('jquery'), require('moment'));
        }
        else {
            factory(jQuery, moment);
        }
    })(function($, moment) {
    ...
    }
```

If I open one of the third party js libs (like bootstrap, fullcalendar, etc) in the VS editor everything is fine.  When I open my lib (which has the same code block as above) the `jQuery` is highlighted and the intellisence note says that I am using an implicitly defined global.  The third party libs do not have this highlighting.

What are they doing that I am not?